# make only part of an image clickable and visible?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Im placing a pennant on a webpage and I only want the pennant shape to be clickable.  This is giving me a real headache because the image's complete dimensions are 320x182. I do not want the complete rectangle to be clickable.

My second problem is getting only the pennant appear on the page. Now, it looks like a white rectangle with a blue pennant inside of it.

```
<a href="http://www.cdm.depaul.edu/Pages/default.aspx"><img alt="depaul" class="transparent" src="/_images/depaul_pennant.jpg" width="" /></a>


.transparent {
background: transparent;
background-color: transparent;
}
```

Any advise would be appreciated.

FYI IM using bootstrap 3.

Comment: Could you recreate the image as a png? pngs support a transparent background. As for only making the visible part of the image clickable, that's an interesting one. I've only dealt with rounded corners, and borderradius seems to work for that.

Comment: I receated as a png.  But how do you set the background as transparent?

Comment: You would have to select all of the white background and remove it from the image. I use GIMP, and the route I would use there is to select the triangle, cut it, and past it is a layer to a transparent background and the export it as a png.

Comment: I'm sure a google search will be able to help more if you need it with converting the background to transparent.

Comment: Thanks!  That sounds like a solid plan of action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/cancerian73/jzPqs/2/

```
.box1 {
width:398px;
height:287px;

 }
```

This is what you are looking at?

Comment: Sorry.  elements that have basic shapes are not a problem for me.  My problem is an image of a pennant (triangle)

Comment: Need to create a personal site for a class: http://michaelbulger.me/
the red is only for troubleshooting!

Comment: something like this<br>

Comment: Impressive.  But now I need a background color that only wraps around the pennant shape. http://jsfiddle.net/jzPqs/1/

Comment: you gotta make your triangle image as png and then use background as transparent in in css